# User who deleted comment is assumed to either be moderator or owner of comment

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface, moderator-tools

When viewing deleted comments on a post, the user who deleted the comment is visible. This is usually a moderator or the owner of the comment; however, some flags on comments containing some patterns are handled automatically, and the flagger appears as the one who deleted the comment. In this case, because the system assumes non-moderators must be comment owners, and the owner of the comment is the asker of the question, the flagger’s username receives asker highlighting too.

[image: Sorry about this screenshot.]

Or, at least, I assume that that’s the case.

Comment: Probably something they aren't going to fix, but still interesting.

Comment: I'm almost considering duping the other one to this one, @Kevin. The red is just... ug! :P

Comment: Oh, hey, it happens for moderators too. I didn’t think it did.

Comment: Some comments can be deleted by one flag. It depends on the flag used and the contents of the comment - this might be one of these cases.

Comment: @ChrisF: I know; that’s not the bug. The bug is the highlighting.

Comment: Ah. Sorry. Misunderstood.